# Converting expressions from Prefix to Postfix ( Facing Problems with Precedence)

Tags: java, algorithm, stack, postfix-notation

I have been attempting to write a code that converts Prefix expressions to Postfix expressions.

So far here's what I have made (note that I am new and hence may not be efficient!)

```
/***************************************************
 NOTE: This code fails to realise the precedence
    of parentheses and $ (exponential) expressions
****************************************************/

import java.util.Scanner;

class Stack{
    //Private Declarations
    private int top;
    private String a[] = new String [100];
    //Public Declarations
    public Stack(){
        top = -1;
        a[0] = "\0";
    }
    public void push(String x){
        if (top != 99){
            a[++top] = x;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Stack overflow");
        }
    };
    public String pop(){
        if (top == -1){
            System.out.println("\nStack empty!");
            return "\n";
        }
        else{
            return a[top--];
        }
    };
    public int ret_top(){
        return top;
    };
}


public class Prefix2Postfix {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Declaration
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        Stack op = new Stack ();
        Stack sym = new Stack ();
        char ch;
        int i;
        String exp, str, str1, str2, str3;

        //Taking input from the user
        System.out.println("Enter the prefix expression : ");
        exp = in.next();

        for (i=0; i<exp.length(); i++){
            ch = exp.charAt(i);
            if((ch == '+')
             ||(ch == '-')
             ||(ch == '*')
             ||(ch == '/')
             ||(ch == '$')){
                str = Character.toString(ch);
                op.push(str);
            }
            else{
                str = Character.toString(ch);
                sym.push(str);
            if (sym.ret_top() == 1){
                str1 = sym.pop();
                str2 = sym.pop();
                str3 = op.pop();
                str1 = str2.concat(str1);
                str1 = str1.concat(str3);
                sym.push(str1);
            }
            }
        }

        //Output
        str = sym.pop();
        System.out.println("After conversion to postfix" + ": " + str);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

As I have already commented in the code, my code fails to realize the precedence in the case of prefix expressions.

For example:

```
Infix   : a + (b*c)
Prefix  : +a*bc 
Postfix : abc*+ //Expected output 
Output I get : ab*c+
```

Is something wrong in the logic I am using or is there something I need to add?
Can you please suggest some method by means of which my code can work properly?
If anybody can help I will be grateful.

NB: Our professor has advised us to write our own stack class and code. Please also note that this is kind of a homework assignment.

Thanks in advance.

---

**Edit:**
In order to make sure that my STACK works fine I wrote the following piece of code and it works perfectly alright.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class STACK {
    //Private Declarations
    private int top;
    private int elem[] = new int [100];
    //Public Declarations
    public STACK (){
        top = -1;
        elem[0] = 0;
    }
    public void push(int x){
        if (top != 99){
            elem[++top] = x;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Stack overflow");
        }
    };
    public int pop(){
        if (top == -1){
            System.out.println("Stack empty!");
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            return elem[top--];
        }
    };
}

public class StackPushPop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        STACK s = new STACK();
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        int choice, x;
        do{
            System.out.println("Menu Options :");
            System.out.println("1 -> Push an element");
            System.out.println("2 -> Pop an element");
            System.out.println("3 -> Empty complete stack");
            System.out.println("Any other input for exit");
            System.out.println("Your choice : ");
            choice = in.nextInt();
            switch(choice){
                case 1: 
                    System.out.println("\nEnter element : ");
                    x = in.nextInt();
                    s.push(x);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.print("\nPopping element : ");
                    x = s.pop();
                    if (x != 0){
                        System.out.println(x);
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("\nEmptying stack!");
                    x = 1;
                    while (x!= 0){
                        x = s.pop();
                        if(x != 0){
                            System.out.print(x + "  ");
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    choice = 0;
            }

        }while (choice != 0);
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT** 
I finally managed to create a program that works perfectly fine.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class STACK{
    private int top, MAX;
    private String a[] = new String [1000];
    public STACK(){
        top = -1;
        MAX = 1000;
        a[0] = "";
    }
    public void push(String x){
        if (top <= MAX-1){
            a[++top] = x;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Stack overflow");
        }
    };
    public String pop(){
        if (top == -1){
            System.out.println("\nStack empty!");
            return "\n";
        }
        else{
            return a[top--];
        }
    };
    public int getTop(){
        return top;
    };
}

public class Prefix2Postfix_STACK{
    static boolean isOperator (char ch){
        switch (ch){
            case '+':
            case '-':
            case '*':
            case '/':
            case '$':
                        return true;
            default :
                        return false;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //declarations
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        String exp;
        int i;
        STACK s = new STACK ();
        String exp_str[] = new String[100];
        String postfix_exp = "\n";

        //input
        System.out.println("Enter prefix expression (No spaces or brackets) : ");
        exp = in.next();

        //create a string array of all characters but in reverse
        for(i=0; i<=exp.length()-1; i++){
            exp_str[exp.length()-1-i]=Character.toString(exp.charAt(i));
        }

        //computing postfix:
        i=0;
        do{ 
            if (!isOperator(exp_str[i].charAt(0)))
                s.push(exp_str[i]);
            else{
                String str1 = s.pop();
                String str2 = s.pop();
                str1 = str1 + str2 + exp_str[i];
                postfix_exp = str1;
                s.push(str1);
            }
            i++;
        }while(s.getTop()>=0 && i!=exp.length());

        //Output
        System.out.println("After converting to postfix : " + postfix_exp);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Should it be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @Pawel : I did not know that there was a special Stack Exchange site for reviewing code.

Comment: Now you will know :). I am asking, because I in my opinion it is better site for your question, but I can go wrong.

Comment: @Pawel [codereview.se] is only appropriate if the code is 100% working (as per [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).

Comment: Why aren't you using the predefined class `java.util.Stack` ?

Comment: I have mentioned it in my question: I am doing a practice assignment and hence it will be better for me if I write my own Stack class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have written only does the job of shifting the operators from left to right.
A nudge in the right direction :

> Insert a condition to check for operators between symbols in the
>   prefix string and solve them first!

This might solve your problem.

Comment: Nope. It didn't. There was an easier method to go about it.